# Construction of a norm in Lp such that it derives from an inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, inner-products

In $L^p((X, \mu),  \mathbb{R})$, $p \geq 2$, it is possible to define the norm
(considering that $\mu(X) = 1$.)

$$||f||_2 = \left( \int_X f(x)^2d \mu(x) \right)^{1/2}$$

which comes from the following inner product

$$<f, g> =  \int_X f(x) g(x) d\mu(x) $$

It is also possible to define all p norms

$$||f||_p = \left( \int_X |f(x)|^p d\mu(x) \right)^{1/p}$$

It is possible to prove that none of these except the one for $p=2$ come from an inner product (correct me if I am wrong), and to generally prove that a given norm comes from an inner product, one needs to show that this norm verifies the parallelogram law.

The question is the following: Are there interesting known ways of constructing such norms that are guaranteed to come from an inner product of the form

$$||f|| = H\left( \int_X G(f(x)) d\mu(x) \right) $$

where $G: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $H: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and ignoring for now the question of whether $G(f(x))$ is actually integrable on $X$.

Let me know if this needs clarification.

Comment: Well, technically you can give that definition of $\lVert f\rVert_2$, but in general it is not *well* defined on $L^p(X,\Bbb R)$, unless, say, $p\ge 2$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$. For instance, $L^p(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)\setminus L^q(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ is non-empty for all $p,q\ge1$ with $p\ne q$; and $L^p([0,1],\Bbb R)\supsetneq L^q([0,1],\Bbb R)$ for all $q>p$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Please consider that $\mu(X) = 1$ and that $p \geq 2$.